# plsql show query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a small problem using oracle pl sql.
I have a sql file with some cursor, etc, and the treatement fail but with no details.
I have an idea about the problem (a function with parameters) but I would like to see the parameter for each call, to be able to debug, to see exactly with wich parameter fail.
This is the message:

```
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 165
ORA-06512: at line 260
```

Is there something to set to be able to see some details ?

I'm launching my treatement like this

```
sqlplus -L $ORA_CONNECT @$FIC_REQ
```

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you try to `Select Into` a variable, but your select returns more than one row.

Check these lines in your script:
`165` and `260` (as displayed in the stacktrace of the error).

---

To output your parameters `dbms_output` should work. Test the following script:

```
Set Serveroutput On

Begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Test');
End;
/
```

Comment: As I said, I have an idea about the error, but I need to see the parameters of a function.

Comment: I tryied with dbms_output.put_line but it does not display anything.
At the beginning I have set serveroutput ON;

Comment: That suggests you're not reaching the point you've put your debug, so you could put `put_line` calls before the call and at earlier points.

Also when running from SQL*Plus, the line numbers reported in the error are within the PL/SQL code, not line numbers of the SQL file itself, so you need to be looking at 165 and 260 lines after your `declare`.

Comment: Ok, I got it, using dbms_output.put_line, I can see the output.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: You're welcome. I just edited my question to explain `dbms_output` when you posted your comment :)

Comment: @CC: if Peter's response was helpful it would be polite to accept it.